# why this error when iam adding the package of audioplayer

Tags: android, flutter, react-native, dart, visual-studio-code

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  ASCII
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 25s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Exited (1).

what is the solution for this error ? and why ?

Comment: can you elaborate the issue more clearly like which package are you using and the complete error log?